# ActiveAttr stops working on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, active-attr

I have created a simple model for handling a contact form:

```
 class ContactForm
   include ActiveAttr::Model

  attribute :name
  attribute :email
  attribute :message

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :message

  validates_presence_of :name, :email, :message
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]    {2,4}$/i
end
```

It works fine on the development environment, but gives me an error on the production server, logged in the unicorn log:

```
E, [2013-01-26T18:15:42.724973 #8940] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ContactForm::ActiveAttr (NameError)
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'
# gem 'acts_as_tree', :git => 'git://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree.git'
gem 'closure_tree'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'slim'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'stamp'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.3.1'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'active_attr'
gem 'select2-rails'
# gem 'roo'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
end

group :development do 
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'letter_opener'
end

group :test do 
  gem 'minitest'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'bullet', :group => :development
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
```

Comment: added the gemfile.. active_attr is in there...

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you restart your prod environment after installing active_attr

Comment: I use capistrano to deploy.. I'm pretty sure it restarts after updating everything.. I restarted unicorn anyways after, and I was still getting the error

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the fix for me was to specify the version of `active_attr` in my `gemfile`.

```
gem 'active_attr', '0.7.0'
```

I found an issue on GitHub where someone else had the same problem [here](https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr/issues/119).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in development environment.
I followed this step-by-step tutorial https://github.com/thomasklemm/email_form_rails.

When I try to create a new message in console I get :

```
m=Message.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Message::ActiveAttr
```

I use Rails 3.2.1, active_attributes gem version is 0.0.1.

EDIT

My fault it seems I made a mistake when installing the gem (not the good one)

change gemfile from
    gem 'active_attributes','0.0.1'

to
    gem 'active_attr', '0.0.7'

Now it seems to work...